# How to execute an ajax script to update form fields in an .xml file rendered by Akeeba FOF?

Tags: component, ajax, fields, fof, simplecrm

I would like to populate the "Owner" select option list by SELECTing the `owner` column from the `#__gscrm_accounts` table WHERE the `gscrm_account_id` (primary key) is the selected "Person or Business" value.

This ajax needs to be triggered by the `onchange()` event of `<field name="account">` then populate `<field name="owner">`.

[image]

To be clear, I don't know if this is "fresh" or "modified" copy of SimpleCRM because I've never used SimpleCRM and this project was just thrown at me.

In **components/com_gscrm/View/Notes/tmpl/form.form.xml**, the "Person or Business" select field is generated from:

```
<field name="account" class="high28" labelclass="label_left" label_placement="top"
    label="COM_GSCRM_NOTES_ACCOUNT_LABEL" tooltip="COM_GSCRM_NOTES_ACCOUNT_DESC"
    type="Model"
    model="Accounts"
    key_field="gscrm_account_id"
    value_field="title"
    apply_access="true"
    apply_enabled="true"
    none="GS_SELECT"
>
    <state key="code">[ITEM:CODE]</state>
</field>
```

The "Owner of this contact" field is generated by:

```
<field name="owner" emptylabel="1" class="high28" labelclass="label_left" label_placement="top" label="COM_GSCRM_NOTES_OWNER_LABEL"
    type="Model"
    model="Beads"
    key_field="gscrm_bead_id"
    value_field="user_name"
    apply_access="true"
    apply_enabled="true"
    none="GS_NOT_AVAILABLE"
>
    <state key="code">[ITEM:CODE]</state>               
</field>
```

I know that I will need to add a bit of complexity to the query that I actually require and it might not be a single "owner" value that I am returning, but my question is: **How do I execute the ajax process using best practices and pre-existing classes/methods if possible?**

I had a look at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_AJAX but that isn't specifically dealing with `<field>` tags.

This looks close: [How to change select list from another using AJAX in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15383822/2943403) but I am not sure about the best placement of the files and I am not dealing with chozen elements.

[Soren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7512519/2943403) indicates that I should be crafting a url like:

```
index.php?option=com_gscrm&task=ajax.getOwners&format=raw&var=[the_selected_value]
```

If so, where do I best park my `getOwners()` method?

[Loading the options of a select form field via jQuery Ajax](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/14280/12352) looks similar, but mostly yatta-yattas over the fundamental pieces that I require:

All of the posts have a fair bit of age on them and I expect to see a token used in this process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JSON format in the controller directly by adding `.json` suffix and changing `format` in your URL to `json`. In this case the controller would be placed in `/administrator/components/com_example/controllers/ajax.json.php`. It's contents:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Response\JsonResponse;

class ExampleControllerAjax extends JControllerLegacy
{
    public function getOwners()
    {
        // Check for request forgeries.
        $this->checkToken();

        // Get our stuff.
        $db = Factory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->quoteName(['name', 'id']))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__example'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $this->input->getInt('exampleId'));
        $result = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObject();

        // Output as JSON
        echo new JsonResponse($result);
    }
}
```

In the form view's layout:

```
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;

// Add session token script.
HTMLHelper::_('behavior.core');

// Optional AJAX error message.
Text::script('COM_EXAMPLE_AJAX_ERROR');
```

AJAX script:

```
// Optional, define namespace.
Example = window.Example || {};

Example.updateOwners = function(exampleId, field) 
{
    // Get session token.
    var token = Joomla.getOptions('csrf.token');

    // Build a selector for the field we want to update. This example is for the filter form.
    var fieldId = '#filter_' + field;

    // Doing it this way so token can be submitted via POST
    var postData = {'exampleId' : exampleId};
    postData[token] = 1;

    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url:  'index.php?option=com_example&task=ajax.getOwners&format=json',
        data: postData,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {

            // Clear existing value.
            jQuery(fieldId).empty();

            // Add new value.
            jQuery('<option />', {value: response.data.id, text: response.data.name}).appendTo(fieldId);

            // Update chosen.
            jQuery(fieldId).trigger("liszt:updated");
        },
        error: function() { Joomla.renderMessages({"warning":[(Joomla.Text._('COM_EXAMPLE_AJAX_ERROR'))]}); },
    });

    return false;
}
```

In the XML form add this to the field that triggers the event. Where `fieldToUpdate` is the name of the field that will be updated.

```
onchange="Example.updateOwners(this.value, 'fieldToUpdate');"
```

This assumes single row is expected from the database. For multiple values, change `loadObject()` to `loadObjectList()` in the controller and run a loop in the script:

```
jQuery.each(response.data, function(){
    jQuery('<option />', {value: this.id, text: this.name}).appendTo(fieldId);
});
```

**The plugin method.** If this is a 3rd party component, we can use a plugin and interact with `com_ajax` instead. The advantage to this is that original files aren't touched at all. This allows to update the component without losing customizations. Instead of modifying the layout, the form file and adding a controller we just have one plugin:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Form\Form;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;
use Joomla\CMS\Session\Session;

class PlgContentExample extends CMSPlugin
{
    protected $app;

    protected $db;

    public function onContentPrepareForm(Form $form, $data)
    {
        // Check that we're manipulating the correct form.
        if ($form->getName() !== 'com_gscrm.Notes.form.form')
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Run only on HTML document.
        if ($this->app->getDocument()->getType() !== 'html')
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Load form token script.
        HTMLHelper::_('behavior.core');

        // Load AJAX script.
        HTMLHelper::_('script', 'plg_content_example/ajax.js', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]);

        // Add error message string.
        Text::script('PLG_CONTENT_EXAMPLE_AJAX_ERROR');

        // Add onchange attribute to the field.
        $form->setFieldAttribute('type', 'onchange', 'Example.updateOwners(this.value, \'owner\');');
    }

    public function onAjaxExample()
    {
        if (!Session::checkToken())
        {
            throw new \Exception('JINVALID_TOKEN');
        }

        // Get our stuff.
        $query = $this->db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($this->db->quoteName(['name', 'id']))
            ->from($this->db->quoteName('#__example'))
            ->where($this->db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $this->app->input->getInt('exampleId'));
        $result = $this->db->setQuery($query)->loadObject();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

In the AJAX script we need only two adjusments:

1) Set the request URL to `com_ajax`:

```
url:  'index.php?option=com_ajax&plugin=example&group=content&format=json',
```

2) When accessing response data, use the first array element:

```
jQuery('<option />', {value: response.data[0].id, text: response.data[0].name}).appendTo(fieldId);
```

Also in this specific case the form does not have a prefix. So the ID selector is simpler:

```
var fieldId = '#' + field;
```

Comment: And that ajax script, am I putting that in `media/com_gscrm/js/getOwners.js` or is there a more sensible place?

Comment: SimpleCRM seems to be doing some weird re-routing thing.  Instead of using `views/notes`, it uses `View/Notes` (but still has index.html files in the `views` subdirectories.  I don't know where to load my `media/com_gscrm/js/getOwners.js` file from.

Comment: @mickmackusa Corrected "your form page" to "form view's layout". Normally that would be `components/com_example/views/someview/tmpl/default.php`.

Comment: I don't see a php file to write into.  This component is weird.  I can do a screen capture of the directories if that helps.  You don't happen to have a copy of your own do you?  https://imgur.com/a/EpMYP73

Comment: The gscrm.php looks like this: https://3v4l.org/nb7H4  I think there is come clever crazy Joomla magic happening with this `dispatch()` call.  Do I need to extend something off of `libraries/fof/dispatcher/dispatcher.php`?

Comment: It appears you have to create a `components/com_gscrm/View/Notes/tmpl/form.php` file to customize form layout. Another option is to add everything to the field class or layout.

Comment: There are many ways to go about this. If it's a 3rd party component and you're not meant to touch it, this could be done entirely in a plugin by using `com_ajax`.

Comment: I've removed some of my less meaningful comments to reduce page bloat.  Can you help me to apply your advice (with Mohamed's addition)?  I am not able to get the json string back from the ajax request.  I reckon it has something to do with the class naming/routing where you have written Example.  Can you have a scan of my attempt? https://pastebin.com/8qNNhneg

Comment: To be clear, the ajax.json.php file is located at components/com_gscrm/controllers/ajax.json.php

Comment: Also, how am I going to generate the token if I am not writing your snippet into a layout .php file?  Can you offer an alternative?

Comment: As a clean alternative I'm offering a plugin method. See updated answer.

Comment: How many of the previous scripts am I still using?  I've created a `plugins/content/o3_gscrm/o3_gscrm.php` and `plugins/content/o3_gscrm/o3_gscrm.xml` files, Discovered, Enabled.  I don't know which files are required for your solution.  I've started replacing `example`s but I have low confidence that I have things pointing in the right direction.  Please clarify.  (My JUG Meetup is starting now, back later.)

Comment: These two plugin files and the JavaScript file containing code for AJAX.

Comment: I'm burning up weeks on this project because I can't manage to perform this very simple task.  I wanted to try to do this the FoF-way, but I'm no longer interested.  Please review my 3 files and tell me where I am going wrong.  There are too many `example` placeholders in your answer and I have a feeling that I am misunderstanding the right values to replace with.  https://pastebin.com/XDZPXRnd  At the moment I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: O3_gscrm is not defined` in my js console.  Can you offer more precise support on this task?

Comment: Your JS file is not loaded. In `HTMLHelper::script()` call either remove `js` folder from path or remove `relative` option and prepend `media` folder to path.

Comment: that fixed it..

Answer (score 3):

This component is developed using [Akeeba FOF](https://github.com/akeeba/fof/wiki), so you need to read the documentation to know how to complete the task.

Almost everything is configured using XML, this is to some extent of course.

To add the onchange javascript code to the dropdown list: https://github.com/akeeba/fof/wiki/XML-Form-Fields#additional-attributes-for-drop-down-list-fields

Also, look at the JSON view to know how to create the json response: https://github.com/akeeba/fof/wiki/The-JSON-view

**EDIT**

To load a js file in this form view, use the `jsfiles` attribute of the form xml element, so in the file components/com_gscrm/View/Notes/tmpl/form.form.xml
change the form definition to be like this

```
<form 
    validate="true"
    jsfiles="media://com_gscrm/js/yourfile.js"
    lessfiles="media://com_gs_bootstrap337/css/gs.less||media://com_gs_bootstrap337/css/bootstrap.css"

>
```

make sure to replace `yourfile.js` with the correct file name.

For more details, look at this page: https://github.com/akeeba/fof/wiki/XML-Forms

**Update**

To be complaint with FOF, do the following:

1. Create a folder in the admin part, name it `Controller`
2. Create a PHP file inside it, name it `Ajax.php`
3. The file contents should look like this:

> ```
> <?php
> /**
>  * 
>  */
>
> namespace Gs\Gscrm\Admin\Controller;
> use FOF30\Controller\Controller;
>
> defined('_JEXEC') or die;
>
> class Ajax extends Controller
> {
>   function getOwners()
>   {
>       // Token check
>       $this->csrfProtection();
>         /* insert your code to get owners in json format*/
>       $this->container->platform->closeApplication();
>   }
> }
> ```

4. Then the ajax call should look like this:

> ```
> $.get(
>               'index.php',
>               {
>                   'option':     'com_gscrm',
>                   'view':       'Ajax',
>                   'format':     'json',
>                   'task':       'getOwners',
>                   '<?php echo $this->container->platform->getToken(true) ?>':   1,
>                   'id':    id
>               },
>               function (data, textStatus)
>               {
>                   // insert here the code to populate the owners list
>               }           )
> ```

Comment: Sharky's advice seems to be a virtually complete solution for my question, but I am stuck trying to figure out how/where to load the ajax script that `onchange()` will point to.  I don't expect to have any difficulties with the other aspects of this task.

Comment: In this kind of projects, js files are installed in the media/com_gscrm/js folder, so try to look for an existing js file that is called in this form view, and load the ajax script there.

Comment: Don't worry, I will try to help after coming back from the break, till then I recommend that you download the akeeba subs or release system extensions and have a look into the code, this may help to discover a solution

Comment: @mickmackusa I have added an example to load a js file in the form view, let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the correct way to add the js file, thank you.  Now there seems to be something wrong with my ajax request in that the json string is not being passed back.  Can you have a look over my stripped down scripts? https://pastebin.com/8qNNhneg  I am skeptical of my class/method naming which Joomla uses to route things properly.

Comment: To be clear, the ajax.json.php file is located at components/com_gscrm/controllers/ajax.json.php

Comment: @mickmackusa I updated the answer with a blueprint on how the Ajax/json call is going in FOF, inspired from the Akeeba Release System component.

Comment: I cannot use `<?php echo $this->container->platform->getToken(true) ?>` as you have mentioned because that is a .js file.  I have seen other .xml files in this component passing `[TOKEN]` like this: `<field name="account" url="index.php?option=com_gscrm&amp;view=Account&amp;id=[ITEM:ACCOUNT]&amp;Itemid=[ITEMID]&amp;nt_show=1&amp;[TOKEN]=1"`.  When I try to use `[TOKEN]` as a parameter of my `updateOwner()` function, it tells me that TOKEN is undefined.  Here is my stripped down triad of files (which is working without a token and with hardcoded values): https://pastebin.com/nQJkFv39

Comment: Did you manage to find out how to do it? sorry I have been busy last days.

Comment: I think the last piece to solve is the generation of the token via the xml file.  Any clues for me?

Comment: Do I need to use `form.php` instead of `form.form.xml` so that I can generate a token?  At this point, I am willing to abandon the xml file if using a php file is the only way to progress.

Comment: I think so, can't find out how to generate the token in the xml form!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish the easy way to do this would be with a bit of jQuery and an ajax call. Add a method to one of your controller files that returns the value of the owner field. Post the id of the person/business filed to that controller using ajax.Return the id of the owner field. Use jQuery to set the option to the appropriate value.

Comment: Sorry this is too vague for what I am after.  Yes, that is generally the action that I wish to perform.  My question is about how to construct the actual scripts and in which directories in accordance with best MVC and security practices.