# Joomla 3. Dependent select in custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, ajax

I make a component for Joomla 3. It has two lists "City" and "Place". How can I make the "Place" list update without reloading the page when I select "City"?

```
<field name="cityid"
type="sql"
class="cityid"
label="Выберите город"
description="Выберите город"
sql_select="e.*"
sql_from="#__lk_cities AS e"
sql_group="title"
sql_order="e.id ASC"
key_field="id"
value_field="title"
 filter="raw"
header="Выберите город"
/>

<field name="placecoolectionid"
type="sql"
label="Выберите место сбора"
description="Выберите сбора"
sql_select="e.*"
sql_from="#__lk_place_collections AS e"
sql_group="title"
sql_order="e.cityid ASC"
sql_filter="cityid"
key_field="id"
value_field="title"
required="true"
class="placecoolectionid"
header="Выберите место сбора"
showon="cityid!:0"
filter="raw"
/>
```

If you do not complicate, give a very detailed answer because I'm new to this

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15383822/2943403

Comment: I do not understand how to do this in my component @mickmackusa

Comment: There are people here smarter than both of us.  Be patient.  If you make any semi-successful strides, edit your question.  Please continue to research and educate yourself.  If you find the solution yourself, please teach others by answering your own question.  In the meantime, please take the [tour] to earn your first badge.

Comment: @Lodder may be able to assist when he next stops in.  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/14280/12352  And sharky has been a lifesaver for me in the past.  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/24369/12352